# Matrix units in commutator subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $m \ge 2$ be an integer, $R = M_{m}(K)$ be the algebra of all $m\times m$ matrices over $K$ an infinite field, if $L = [R,R]$ and $a,p \in R$ are non-zero elements. Then, if $[au, pu] = 0$ for all $u \in L$, then $a= \alpha p$ for some $\alpha \in K$.

I am reading a proof of above lemma and what I don't get is the following:

If $a = \Sigma_{ij}\  a_{ij}e_{ij}$ and $p =\Sigma_{ij} p_{ij}e_{ij}$ for some $a_{ij},p_{ij} \in K\backslash \{0\}$ with $1 \le i,j \le m$. Then, for every $1 \le i \neq j \le m$ we have $0 = e_{kk}[ae_{ij},pe_{ij}] = (a_{ki}p_{ji} - p_{ki}a_{ji})e_{kj}$

I can prove the first equality but have trouble with the second one. Is there some trick to see this or is this just plain calculation? I have tried to calculate the bracket explicitly by writing terms, but it gets a more complicated cause of matrix unit elements ($e_{ij}$). Maybe I missed some trivial detail, any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be obtained by direct calculation:
\begin{aligned}
e_{kk}[ae_{ij},pe_{ij}]
&=e_{kk}ae_{ij}pe_{ij}-e_{kk}pe_{ij}ae_{ij}\\
&=e_k(e_k^Tae_i)(e_j^Tpe_i)e_j^T-e_k(e_k^Tpe_i)(e_j^Tae_i)e_j^T\\
&=e_k(a_{ki}p_{ji}-p_{ki}a_{ji})e_j^T\\
&=(a_{ki}p_{ji}-p_{ki}a_{ji})e_{kj}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: I got the trick in step 1 but I didn't get how you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: @Rick In general, $e_k^TM$ is the $k$-th row of a matrix $M$ and $Me_i$ is the $i$-th column of $M$. Therefore, $e_k^Tae_i$ is the $i$-th column of the $k$-th row of $a$, i.e. the $(k,i)$-th entry of $a$, or $a_{ki}$.

Comment: Sorry for my unfamiliarity with matrix units, but what I read from wiki, isn't $e_{k}^{T}M = 0$ as they are product of $1\times k$ and $m\times m$ matrix?

Comment: @Rick $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m\}$ denotes the canonical basis of $K^m$ here. That is, $e_k\in K^m$ is a column vector with $m$ entries, with a $1$ at the $k$-th position and zeroes elsewhere. E.g. when $m=3$, we have $e_1=(1,0,0)^T,\,e_2=(0,1,0)^T$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)^T$. This is almost a standard notation in linear algebra. With this definition, we have $e_{rs}=e_re_s^T$ for any $r,s$.

Comment: Oh, it was simple, just got confused with notations. Thanks.